# Cannot Create Active X component inside a windows service.

Tags: c#, vb.net, com, openoffice.org, dcom

As per a project requirement, I wrote a multiple document converter/exporter relying upon the COM interfaces presented by OpenOffice. My idea was to write a windows service that instantiates OO Writer as a COM Object via `VB.NET`, opens an appropriately formatted HTML file and converts it in DOCX, PDF, and whatnot. The converter must run on a Windows Server 2008R2 machine.

I have already written a Windows service encapsulating the converter's code. The problem is that, if I run the service in `Environment.UserInteractive` mode (that is as a normal Windows app) everything runs fine.

If I install the whole thing as a Windows Service, even with Administrator credentials, the service grinds to an halt when trying to create the first object:

```
Public Sub StartServices()
    Dim l As New List(Of String)
    Try
        If (Log.IsInfoEnabled) Then Log.Info("Creazione del servizio com.sun.star.ServiceManager")
        objServiceManager = CreateObject("com.sun.star.ServiceManager")
        If (Log.IsInfoEnabled) Then Log.Info("Creazione del servizio com.sun.star.reflection.CoreReflection")
        objCoreReflection = objServiceManager.createInstance("com.sun.star.reflection.CoreReflection")
        If (Log.IsInfoEnabled) Then Log.Info("Creazione del servizio com.sun.star.frame.Desktop")
        objDesktop = objServiceManager.createInstance("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop")
        gfxLoader = objServiceManager.createInstance("com.sun.star.graphic.GraphicProvider")
        If (Log.IsInfoEnabled) Then Log.Info("Creazione filtri di import")
        initialize_import_filters()
        If (Log.IsInfoEnabled) Then Log.Info("Creazione filtri di export")
        initialize_export_filters()
    Catch e As Exception
        Throw New Exception("Errore nell'avvio dei servizi di conversione\n" + String.Join(vbCrLf, l.ToArray()), e)
    End Try

End Sub
```

This is what I find in logfile:

```
Impossibile creare il componente ActiveX.
in Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.CreateObject(String ProgId, String ServerName)
```

(Cannot create ActiveX component)

I've tried to tinker with DCOM settings and user permission but I can't make the service communicate with OO.

Any pointers about this problem?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know about OpenOffice, but regular Office isn't designed to run as a service, and will fail spectacularly in all sorts of ways.  Off the top of my head, services run with the default user profile, and not as a logged on user.

Comment: I browsed extensively StackOverflow and MS forums but it seems that, when it comes to edge cases regarding ActiveX/COM usage, there is little or no literature, maybe because 1) A lot of what used to be COM services have been migrated, in the last 15 years to .NET assemblies and 2) ActiveX/COM used this way are huge security holes. Regarding #2, the whole thing will run in a protected environment, but regarding #1 and project requirements -- that is something that reads HTML and spits it in DOCX,PDF, whatnot -- I think that I'll have to turn my windows service into a normal Windows program.

Comment: @MaxLambertini , Did you find any solution for this? I have a very similar problem and I'm unable to find out any solution.

Comment: Alas no, we abandoned Open Office as document converting framework and we ended up buying a commercial solution. Sorry.